# Add variable number of variables

Tags: bash, variable

I need to parse a CSV file for certain fields, and based on matching a pattern I need to add fields together. I've succeeded in setting variables, but need help figuring out how to add them when there may be 1-20 variables. (Or possibly another, simpler way to approach this.)

Source file contents example:

```
Server-Name,Volume-Name,Vol-Size,Logical-Space-In-Use
FTWTRAQNETSQL01,FTWTRAQNETSQL01_e,2008,1989
FTWTRAQNETSQL01,FTWTRAQNETSQL01_f,106,63.698
FTWTRAQNETSQL02,FTWTRAQNETSQL02_e,2008,1989
FTWTRAQNETSQL02,FTWTRAQNETSQL02_f,106,4.155
ftwvocmpsqln01,ftwvocmpsqln01_1,1002,21.047
ftwvocmpsqln01,ftwvocmpsqln01_2,104,55.379
ftwspsqln02,ftwspsqln02_H,501,0
ftwvocmpsqln02,ftwvocmpsqln02_1,1002,20.732
ftwvocmpsqln02,ftwvocmpsqln02_2,104,55.380
```

Output should be one line for each each unique server name, and adding all the field 3 values and  all the field 4 values. Servers can have many volumes, some as many as 20. Desired file output would be:

```
Server-Name,Vol-Size,Logical-Space-In-Use
FTWTRAQNETSQL01,2114,2052.698
FTWTRAQNETSQL02,2114,1993.155
ftwvocmpsqln01,1106,76.426
ftwspsqln02,501,0
ftwvocmpsqln02,1106,76.112
```

I can do this in about 7 seconds in Excel, but so far haven't figured out a solution for automating with bash (or other shells.)

This is the code I have so far, only looking at field 3. It correctly sets variables for each iteration of unique servers, but I can't figure out how to do the addition with a variable number of variables.

```
for i in $( awk -F , '{print $1}' $REPORT | grep -v Server-Name | uniq )
do
    c=0
    for num in $( grep $i $REPORT | awk -F , '{print $3}' )
        do
        eval "var$c=$num";
        c=$((c+1));
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a shell, but "unix way":

```
awk -F',' 'NR==1; NR>1{s3[$1]+=$3; s4[$1]+=$4} END { for(i in s3){printf("%s,%s,%s\n",i,s3[i],s4[i])} }' file
```

The order of the output will (probably) not match the input order.

## Description:

```
awk                   # use awk.
-F','                 # set the field separator as comma (,)
'                                         # start an awk script.
   NR==1;                                 # print first line (header)
   NR>1{                                  # for lines other than first
         s3[$1]+=$3;                      # add values on third field
         s4[$1]+=$4                       # add values on fourth field
       }                                  # close the previous {
         END {                            # after all lines have been read
               for(i in s3){              # for each index of the array
                                          # (all unique values of field $1)
                             printf("%s,%s,%s\n",i,s3[i],s4[i])   # print values.
                           }              # close the for loop.
             }                            # close the END loop.
' file                                    # end script code and name the file.
```

Comment: That seems to work! Thanks! (Now I just have to take it apart so I understand what you're doing.)

Comment: @TeresaM Description added ....

Comment: Thank you, @Isaac. Much appreciate it, so I don't have to ask the next time I need this type function.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU datamash:

```
$ datamash -t, --header-in groupby 1 sum 3,4 < file.csv
FTWTRAQNETSQL01,2114,2052.698
FTWTRAQNETSQL02,2114,1993.155
ftwvocmpsqln01,1106,76.426
ftwspsqln02,501,0
ftwvocmpsqln02,1106,76.112
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (`mlr`) to compute the sums of the two columns `Vol-Size` and `Logical-Space-In-Use`, grouping by the `Server-Name` field:

```bash
$ mlr --csv stats1 -a sum -f Vol-Size,Logical-Space-In-Use -g Server-Name file
Server-Name,Vol-Size_sum,Logical-Space-In-Use_sum
FTWTRAQNETSQL01,2114,2052.698000
FTWTRAQNETSQL02,2114,1993.155000
ftwvocmpsqln01,1106,76.426000
ftwspsqln02,501,0
ftwvocmpsqln02,1106,76.112000
```